# Can I prevent summary.coxph from truncating coefficient names

Tags: r, survival-analysis

After running a cox proportional hazards model with penalized splines, the summary table truncates the row names of the coefficients. Is there a way to print the full parameter or to increase the truncation limit to ensure full row names.

Modeling some dummy data:

```
library(survival)

dummy = data.frame(
  survival = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1), 
  time = c(60,120,180,240,300,360,60,120,180,240,60,120,180,240,300,360,420,480,60,120,180,60,120,180,240), 
  cov1 = c(9.1,7.3,8.2,0.9,0.7,8.7,6.3,7.6,1.5,2.9,1.9,1.3,6.4,1.3,8.9,1.6,7.8,1.2,0.8,5.4,3.5,2.2,4.8,9.3,5.5), 
  covariate2 = c(323,378,261.5,324,492,246.5,330.5,268,77.5,254.5,216,224,206,159.5,76,227.5,444,379,71,232,139,461,366,380,350.5))

mod_survival <- coxph(Surv(time, survival) ~ pspline(cov1) + pspline(covariate2, df = 2), data = dummy)
summary <- summary(mod_survival)
summary$coefficients
```

Results in the following:

```
> summary$coefficients
                                 coef se(coef)      se2        Chisq         DF         p
pspline(cov1), linear      0.01186380 4.180302 4.042494 8.054382e-06  1.0000000 0.9977356
pspline(cov1), nonlin              NA       NA       NA 1.090602e-01  6.4931508 0.9999908
pspline(covariate2, df =  -0.04858999 8.095739 7.212111 3.602306e-05  1.0000000 0.9952112
pspline(covariate2, df =           NA       NA       NA 2.154301e-10 -0.2063786 0.9964457
```

How can I print out the something like below?

```
                                              coef se(coef)      se2        Chisq         DF         p
pspline(cov1), linear                   0.01186380 4.180302 4.042494 8.054382e-06  1.0000000 0.9977356
pspline(cov1), nonlin                           NA       NA       NA 1.090602e-01  6.4931508 0.9999908
pspline(covariate2, df = 2), linear    -0.04858999 8.095739 7.212111 3.602306e-05  1.0000000 0.9952112
pspline(covariate2, df = 2), nonlin             NA       NA       NA 2.154301e-10 -0.2063786 0.9964457
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `maxlabel` argument in the `summary.coxph.penal()` function controls the length of coefficient names. You can see the source code by running `getAnywhere(summary.coxph.penal)` after loading the survival package. The default value is `maxlabel = 25`, as you can see from the example.

Changing the `summary()` call to `summary <- summary(mod_survival, maxlabel = 35)`, or a greater number, solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your clear and concise answer, its exactly what I needed.